# How do i write a shell script for checking website live or not

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I am writing a shell script to monitor website live or not and send an email alert below is my code

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ curl -s --head  --request GET http://opx.com/opx/version | grep "200 OK" > /dev/null] && [ curl -s --head --request GET http://oss.com/version | grep "200 OK" > /dev/null ]]
then echo "The HTTP server on opx.com and oss.com is up!" #> /dev/null
else
msg="The HTTP server  opx.com Or oss.com is down "
email="opx-noc@opx.com"

curl --data "body=$msg &to=$email &subject=$msg" https://opx.com/email/send
fi;
```

if i run this code i got

```
./Monitoring_Opx_Oss: line 2: conditional binary operator expected
./Monitoring_Opx_Oss: line 2: syntax error near `-s'
./Monitoring_Opx_Oss: line 2: `if [[ curl -s --head  --request GET http://opx.com/opx/version | grep "200 OK" > /dev/null] && [ curl -s --head --request GET http://oss.com/version | grep "200 OK" > /dev/null ]] '
```

Please correct me...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change it do this:

```
if [ $(curl -s --head  --request GET http://opx.opera.com/opx/version | grep "200 OK" > /dev/null) ] && [ $(curl -s --head --request GET http://oss.opera.com/version | grep "200 OK" > /dev/null) ]
```

To check the status of a command inside an `if`, you have to do it like

```
if [ $(command) ]
```

while you were using

```
if [ command]
```

note also the need of spaces around `[ ]`: `if [_space_ command _space_ ]`

#### Update

Based on [Ansgar Wiechers's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522360/how-do-i-write-a-shell-script-for-checking-website-live-or-not/17522397#comment25479179_17522397), you can also use the following:

```
if curl -s --head  --request GET http://opx.com/opx/version | grep "200 OK" > /dev/null && curl -s --head --request GET http://oss.com/version | grep "200 OK" > /dev/null;
```

That is,

```
if command && command
```

Comment: It would also work without any square brackets: `if command`. And for correctnes, he's using `if [[ command ]]`, not `if [ command ]`.

Comment: Good one! I wasn't aware of that, @AnsgarWiechers. He is using `if [[ ] && []]`, so `[[` is to make it contain two conditions.

Comment: You have to end a `fi` at the end of the instance, @Akki: `then echo "Server is up"; fi`